# UserPrincipalName (UPN) in SAMLResponse from ADFS

Tags: java, active-directory, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

I am implementing an SP initiated SSO with ADFS. I submit `SAMLRequest` to ADFS and after validating `SAMLRequest`, ADFS responds with a `SAMLResponse`.
In ADFS, the claim rules map UPN to Name ID. But I am unable to see Name ID or UPN in the `SAMLResponse`. Is it something I have to tell ADFS in my `SAMLRequest` or is it some configuration issue at ADFS?

Here is my SAMLRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://http://testurl.com/mysite/samlrequest"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="_bec424fa5103428909a30ff1e31168327f79474984"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2015-04-22T11:49:03.815Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://testurl.com/mysite</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Comment: Is it showing up in `<AttributeStatement>` section of the assertion instead of `<Subject>` section?

Comment: Did you use a transform rule?

Comment: @explunit the SAMLResponse I've recieved doesnot contain <AttributeStatement> or <Subject> elements at all.

Comment: Do I need to mention in the SAMLRequest to get UPN or Name ID in Response, if yes, then how ?

Comment: I've also added the SAMLRequest in question now.

Comment: Can you post the assertion response that you are seeing?  Is it possible that ADFS is giving you a Responder error rather than an assertion?

Comment: the current response from ADFS would be helpfull. Basically you could send a NameIDPolicy with the SAMLRequest. But I expect you need to setup a default NameIdPolicy handling on ADFS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your claim rule looks like, but I map email address attribute to nameidentifier and it works. This should be custom rule in ADFS and should look like:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "SP_ENTITY_ID");`

If you want to send this as attribute, just create rule using 'send LDAP Attributes as Claims"

I know it's late, but hope this helps someone.